# Alias para consulta en dos tablas con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

¿Hay alguna forma abreviada de identificar las columnas de cada tabla creando la consulta de esta manera?

```
$product = Product::with(['order'])->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->find($id);
```

Por ejemplo especificando algo así:

```
->where('order.user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
```

user_id es un campo de la tabla order, el ejemplo no funciona ya que **no reconoce el campo user_id**.

O para este tipo de consultas necesito utilizar si o si el buldier DB::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso está la función whereHas, la cual realiza una consulta en la relación:

```
->whereHas('order', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
})->find($id);
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence